# Creating Non-Proxy API Gateway for Lambda Event using SAM Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I followed an AWS tutorial for setting up Lambda + API Gateway using SAM Template.
But the event defined under lambda template creates a Proxy integration.
I followed this tutorial because I wanted to set up similar for one of my projects.
I need Non-proxy integration for that specific use case. Because I have to return xml format to the client and this can be only done by modifying the Integration Response.
But in proxy APIs integration response cannot be modified.
I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer.
For now the template.yaml looks like this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  callforward

  Sample SAM Template for callforward

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
So if anyone stumble upon this stupid question, this is for you.
The whole point of Proxy API gateway with Lambda is to just return whatever the lambda returns.

I was able to do my requirement using Proxy API itself.
Follow this thread as a starting point, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=649836

I was asked to move this thing to a new AWS account, saw the code that I wrote before, cringed at it and rewrote it.
As writing this, I am cringing at why I asked this stupid question in the first place.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken, any idea how to create non-proxy integration in sam template file? I just want to keep my API Gateway the same as I created from the web console.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is the "Mapping template" functionality of API Gateway.
Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do it in the AWS SAM.

But there is a way you can achieve this by leveraging the Open API support inside the AWS SAM which has a subset of API Gateway extensions. (x-amazon-API gateway-integration.requestTemplates object)

```
RestApi:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
Properties:
    DefinitionBody:       
        <add openAPI defintaion>
```

[API Gateway Extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-api-gateway-extensions.html)

[OpenAPI definitions of sample API integrated with a Lambda function](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-as-lambda-proxy-export-swagger-with-extensions.html)